# useState hook keep returning initailState after setState

Tags: arrays, reactjs, setstate, use-state

I have a problem, I have an empty array as an initial value of a const. I want to concat booleons to it after some condition occur (cardImgIndex === imgIndex). The problem is that when I want to copy previous state it always is initial ([]) and I don't know why. Below code example:

```
const [correctPlacementMap, setCorrectPlacementMap] = useState<any>([])


 const handleDrop = (e: React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
        const {draggedCardID, cardImgIndex} = JSON.parse(e.dataTransfer.getData('card'));
        if (isEmpty) {
            if (cardImgIndex === imgIndex) {
                setCorrectPlacementMap((prevState: boolean[]) => [...prevState, true]);
                e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(draggedCardID))
            } else {
                setCounter((prevState: number) => prevState + 10);
                e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(draggedCardID))
            }
        }
    };
```

It sets the array correctly (after first drop is [true], but after another drop prevState is [].

handleDrop method is fired on drop event.

Comment: Does this help `setCorrectPlacementMap([... correctPlacementMap, true])`?

Comment: why are you initializing  your state with `{}` instead of `[]`?

Comment: @Naren it does not help.

Comment: @thedude it is a typo, of course should be ([]) - still not working

Comment: Can you create a fiddle

Comment: are you calling `setCorrectPlacementMap` anywhere else?

Comment: another option is that your component is being unmounted and re-mounted

Comment: @thedude thanks a lot, the problem was, that I put state in child instead of passing just setStateAction. I pulled up state to parent and the problem disappeared.